# Deleting a front door backend by address, not index

Tags: azure-cli, azure-front-door

Using the Azure CLI, I would like to remove a series of backends from a Front Door backend pool based on their address. But from what I can tell you need to know the position of the backends in the list (the index) rather than pick from the address.

I am using `az network front-door backend-pool backend list` to get the list of backends, the response does not provide an index to use.

- Can I remove a backend by the address, or some other identifier, rather than an index?

If I am forced to delete by index:

- If I list the backends multiple times, can I be guaranteed that they always come back in the same order?
- If I add a new backend to the pool, is it always the last in the list, and therefore the highest index?
- If I delete the first backend (index = 1), does that index get replaced with the next in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Azure CLI only provides a way with an index to remove a backend. But you can use the command below to get the index of a backend that you want to remove by its address:

```
backends=$(az network front-door backend-pool backend list --resource-group <resource group name> --front-door-name <front door name> --pool-name <pool name>)
echo $backends |jq

echo $backends | jq  '[ .[] | .address == "stantest1016.blob.core.windows.net" ] | index(true) +1'
```

Result:
[image]

It is recommended that query backend list to get the latest list after add/remove backends.

Comment: Thanks, Stanley, I appreciate the effort you went to in your response to determine the index. If removing by the index is the only method, I am concerned that I have to rely on the list always being in the same order (am I guaranteed that the list always returns in the same order?) and that there have been no changes to the list since I last queried for the backends. 

Relying on the position in a list when I can't be sure the list I have is accurate does not make me confident when removing production backends.

Comment: @FreeRangeEggs, welcome, I can totally understand it, the way that removing backends is a little bit weird, not so strict. Per my testing, the backend list that you get from CLI command could changes each time you modify(add/remove) it,and before you modify it next time, the list will not change so that we can identify the index to remove some backends. If you want to do any operations based on the index, I think you need to call the list backend method again to get the latest backend list so that you can find the instance correctly by the index